# how to sort within a functional boost query in elasticsearch

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch, lucene

I have an index containing details regarding mobiles, case covers etc.

Below is the query used.

```
{
"query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": { "match": {"title" :"Apple iPhone 6s"} },
      "boost": "5", 
      "functions": [
          {
              "filter": { "match": { "main_category": "mobiles"             } },
              "weight": 8
          },
          {
              "filter": { "match": {"main_category": "cases-and-covers"  } },
              "weight": 6
          }
      ],
      "max_boost": 8,
      "score_mode": "max",
      "boost_mode": "multiply",
      "min_score" : 5
    }
},
"_source":["title","main_category","selling_price"],
"size" : 1000
```

}

Is it possible to boost mobiles category like below and sort within the mobiles category by selling price ascending order.

Boost is working fine. How to sort within the specific boost function?

If user searched for **apple iphone 6s**,I want **mobiles** category to be boosted and **lowest price** should comes first and then case and cover category products also in selling price ascending order.

Below are the results needed

```
{
   "took": 6,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 104,
      "max_score": 40.645245,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "products",
            "_id": "shop_24",
            "_score": 40.645245,
            "_source": {
               "selling_price": 72000,
               "main_category": "mobiles",
               "title": "Apple iPhone 6s"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "products",
            "_id": "shop_20",
            "_score": 40.168346,
            "_source": {
               "selling_price": 82000,
               "main_category": "mobiles",
               "title": "Apple iPhone 6s Plus"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "products",
            "_id": "shop_15",
            "_score": 39.365562,
            "_source": {
               "selling_price": 92000,
               "main_category": "mobiles",
               "title": "Apple iPhone 6s Plus"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "products",
            "_id": "shop_17",
            "_score": 39.365562,
            "_source": {
               "selling_price": 2000,
               "main_category": "cases-and-covers",
               "title": "Case cover for Apple iPhone 6s"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "products",
            "_id": "shop_18",
            "_score": 39.365562,
            "_source": {
               "selling_price": 2300,
               "main_category": "cases-and-covers",
               "title": "Case cover for Apple iPhone 6s Plus"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Please help?.

Comment: can you show what you want to achieve?

Comment: Question updated. Please check.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try following query:

```
{
"query": {
  "function_score": {
     "query": {
        "match_all": {}          // Change this to query as per your need
     },
     "boost": "5",
     "functions": [
        {
           "filter": {
              "match": {
                 "main_category": "mobiles"
              }
           },
           "weight": 50
        },
        {
           "filter": {
              "match": {
                 "main_category": "cases-and-covers"
              }
           },
           "weight": 25
        }
      ]

     }
    },
   "sort": [
   {
     "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
     }
   },
   {
     "selling_price": {
        "order": "asc"
     }
   }
  ]
 }
```

We are providing high weight `weight=50` to the documents which have **mobile** category and low weight `weight=25`  to the documents which have **case-and-cover** category.

Finally We are sorting first on the basis of score and then selling price.

Comment: Seems working fine in some cases. But _score is calculating wrong in somecases. How is _score calculated?

Comment: Can you provide the case for which it does not work?

Comment: By using this technique, It will sort according to _score first and if same _score appears then it will sort price ascending.  But I need to sort irrespective of _score, like I have to boost the category and then sort within category using price asc. Suppose, If two category is there mobiles and case-covers, then I need to sort all products in mobile category using price asc and then same for case-covers also.

Comment: Or the _score should be same for same category for all products and then sort by _score will work.